# How to present a UIViewController after sometime in background in Swift?

Tags: swift, ios9, nstimer, appdelegate

I have this app that will present a passcode screen when the app comes back from background or is launched for the second time and all the others that will follow.

But I need to only be presented if the app was on background for at least 30seconds and not less than that.

How can I do that?

The code I have to load present the passcode screen is at AppDelegate.swift:

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    //Load lock screen
    let topController = self.topViewControllerWithRootViewController(UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window??.rootViewController)

    let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let displayedWalkthrough = userDefaults.boolForKey("Walk")

    if displayedWalkthrough {
        let main : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let lockVC = main.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LockVC") as! LockVC
        topController.presentViewController(lockVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } else {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to create a background task and set a flag after 30 seconds that you read in `applicationDidBecomeActive()`. You'll have to use `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler`, [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:). For example (make `task` a global):

On entering background:

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    task = application.beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler({})
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(30 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))), dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults.setBool(true, forKey: "lock")
    }
    application.endBackgroundTask(task)
}
```

On launch:

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    if NSNSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults.boolForKey("lock") {
        // show lock
    }
    application.endBackgroundTask(task)
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults.setBool(true, forKey: "lock")
    // rest of your code
}
```